# React Respond to Property Object Change

Tags: reactjs, object, properties, parent-child, react-component

I'm looking for a way to update a React.Component when the internal state of one of its properties (an object) changes.

Example:

```
export class ParentClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.someObject = new SomeObject();
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return <ChildClass someObject=this.someObject />
    }
}
```

When I call `this.someObject.change()` in the parent class. How can I signal to the child class that it should re-render since the internal state of someObject just changed?

Normally, if I updated a primitive value, I believe this would trigger a re-render of the child. However, since the object pointer hasn't changed, I don't believe the child class is aware a change has occurred.

Is it possible to trigger a re-render of `ChildClass` in this case? Is there maybe a better convention for managing this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

This could have a performance impact, but I resolved this by moving `someObject` into the state of the parent and setting the Child property to `{this.state.someObject}`.

When someObject (in this case `roadTileMatrix`) changes, I clone the object, make the changes, then set the new object as the state. This seems to be a common pattern from my reading.

Alternatively, as a more lightweight solution, it looks like you could instead set a `key` value in the state that will change each time changes are made to someObject, triggering a re-render of the child.

Code here:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { RoadTileMatrix, Grid } from './Grid';
import { TravelGraph } from './TravelGraph';

export class RoadNetwork extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const rows = this.props.rows;
        const cols = this.props.cols;

        this.state = {
            roadTileMatrix: new RoadTileMatrix(rows, cols, null)
        };

        this.addTile = this.addTile.bind(this);
    }

    addTile(r, c) {
        const rows = this.props.rows;
        const cols = this.props.cols;
        const oldArray = this.state.roadTileMatrix.innerArray;

        const newRoadTileMatrix = new RoadTileMatrix(rows, cols, oldArray);
        newRoadTileMatrix.addTile(r, c, true);

        this.setState({
            roadTileMatrix: newRoadTileMatrix,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid roadTileMatrix={this.state.roadTileMatrix} addTile={this.addTile} />
                <TravelGraph />
            </div>
        );
    };
}

RoadNetwork.propTypes = {
    rows: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    cols: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}
```